# SCSS Opacity build bug?

Tags: reactjs, sass

I use `opacity: 100%` or `opacity: 40%` in some SCSS code in my React app.

Works fine in development mode.

But when I build, all the elements have their opacity set to `1%`!!!

I've worked around this easily by using RGBA colors and setting opacity there.

But, what is up with this???

Comment: opacity is 0 to 1 as decimal, percentage is invalid in the first place. So by spec 0% = 0, 100% = 1, 50% = .5, 25% = .25, etcetera. Sounds to me like it's giving you more than it should in the first place and the problem disappears when you use proper property semantics. :)

Comment: They should at least make it consistent. Cause % works in dev but not in build. That's kinda dangerous :(

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Opacity is not run by percentage but by decimals so:

- opacity: 1; is 100%
- opacity: .5; is 50%;
- opacity: 0; is 0%;

See more on opacity css spec here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity

Comment: As of today (May 19, 2020), the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity#Syntax) says percentage is an accepted unit, and Chrome honors that in the stylesheet and when changing it in the debugger.  It's frustrating and easy to miss that only the prod build attempt the conversion :/

Comment: Good point @JohnNeuhaus! I do see support is fairly limited still but I didn't know the spec had changed: https://caniuse.com/#search=opacity%20percent

Comment: Yep. I simply replaced everywhere I used a percentage to a decimal between 0 and 1 and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Sass never changes property values based on property names (see [this example](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/38e6c7289c7caad9751d00b55a36f65c)). I'm guessing you're using cssnano as well, in which case you're running into [this bug](https://github.com/cssnano/cssnano/issues/957) for which a fix will be released soon.